# Get systemd actual state

Tags: debian, boot, systemd

How can we know if systemd has finished to boot the system ?

I don't want to execute on cron job if the system is actually on boot process because of missing network connectivity. My script launched by cron would have a test on top, and it exits if the booting process is not finished like

```
#!/bin/sh
$STATE=`HERE ADD THE MISSING PART`
if [ $STATE != "active" ]; then
  exit
fi
# Actions to do on next cron after booting
```

If it can also provide me the information about shutting down process, as the problem can be the same..;

I was doing this with SystemV with *runlevel* command, but Systemd do not change the runlevel at end of boot.

Thanks

Comment: Use a systemd unit instead of cron and use `After=network-online.target` and/or `Wants=network-online.target` to start it after the network.

Comment: You can run scripts at shutdown with systemd [in a similar way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)

Comment: @Gerald_Schneider : I must run the command regulary by cron, but I don't want to execute them if the boot process is not finished...

Comment: systemd supports timer units which would satisfy that requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the target you need to be active in order for your script to run. For example, in order for the network to be accessible, you need to check the `network-online.target` (`systemctl check` will return 0 if the checked unit is active)

The target systemd tries to reach is its "default" target, which can be queried by `systemctl get-default`. If that target is online, the system has finished booting (so you can issue `systemctl status $(systemctl get-default)` to check whether the boot process has finished)

**Edit:**
If you want to monitor only the current state of the system, and you aren't interested in targets (i.e. you want to run your command only when *everything* is up and running), it is better to use the `systemctl is-system-running` command. It will output `running` is everything is fine, or `degraded` if the system is up but some of the services have failed (which may or may not indicate an error). The other states would indicate that your script shouldn't run. As a side note, it's usually better to check return values instead of parsing the text output, but the manpage doesn't specify return values, only says that anything other than "running" results of a nonzero exit code, so it might be safer to parse the output text.

See the manpage of `systemctl` for the possible output values.

Comment: And do you know how to catch when the system is going to halt as the same way ?

Comment: Yes, use the `is-system-running` subcommand. I've updated my answer to include this as well.